# AdMob not showing. Not enough space to show ad ( Fragment file )

Tags: android, android-layout, admob

I hope all fine.

I was trying to add AdMob ads to my application. I'd like to add a banner right under a WebView.

There is no ads are shown and logs look like there's not enough space for the banner to show up.

> W/Ads: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has
>   0x561 dp.
>
> W/Ads: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has
>   0x505 dp.

My **SingleNewsArticleFragment** is :

```
package com.xx.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.ecloud.pulltozoomview.PullToZoomScrollViewEx;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.FirebaseUserActions;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.builders.Actions;
import com.mikepenz.fontawesome_typeface_library.FontAwesome;
import com.mikepenz.iconics.IconicsDrawable;
import com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsTextView;
import com.almowaten.helpers.OnSwipeTouchListener;
import com.almowaten.helpers.PrettyTime;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import static com.almowaten.news.R.id.descriptionView;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.FirebaseAppIndex;
import com.google.firebase.appindexing.Indexable;

/**
 * Created by melvin on 03/06/2017.
 */

public class SingleNewsArticleFragment extends Fragment {
    private AdView mAdView;
    private AdRequest adRequest;

    private static final String TAG = "SingleNewsArticleFragment";
    TextView titleView, dateView, breakingView;
    WebView textView;
    NewsArticle newsArticle;
    PullToZoomScrollViewEx scrollView;
    ImageView propertyImage;
    IconicsTextView photosView;

    int ItemId;
    boolean isFeatureImage = true;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        ViewGroup fragmentContentView;
        ViewGroup contentView;
        final View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_content_view, container, true);
        mAdView = rootview.findViewById(R.id.adView2);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        //is feature image enabled
        isFeatureImage = Preference.getCached(getContext(), "showfeatureimage").equals("1");

        if (isFeatureImage) {
            //Feature image is enabled so show image on top
            fragmentContentView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_single_news_feature_img, container, false);

            //set zoom, content and header view
            scrollView = (PullToZoomScrollViewEx) fragmentContentView.findViewById(R.id.scroll_view);
            View headView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.article_head_view, null, false);
            View zoomView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.article_zoom_view, null, false);
            contentView = (ViewGroup) LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.article_content_view, null, false);
            scrollView.setHeaderView(headView);
            scrollView.setZoomView(zoomView);
            scrollView.setScrollContentView(contentView);

            //set aspect ratio of header image
            DisplayMetrics localDisplayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(localDisplayMetrics);
            int mScreenWidth = localDisplayMetrics.widthPixels;
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams localObject = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(mScreenWidth, (int) (9.0F * (mScreenWidth / 16.0F)));
            scrollView.setHeaderLayoutParams(localObject);

            //get article image element
            propertyImage = (ImageView) zoomView.findViewById(R.id.image);

            //handle image swipe/clicks
            propertyImage.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener(getActivity()) {

                @Override
                public void onClick() {
                    openFullScreenImage();

                }

                @Override
                public void onSwipeLeft() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSwipeRight() {
                }

            });

            //photos counter
            photosView = (IconicsTextView) headView.findViewById(R.id.photos);
        } else {
            //feature image not enabled. So just show the content view.
            fragmentContentView = contentView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.article_content_view, container, false);
        }


        //get article prices elements
        titleView = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        dateView = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.dateView);
        breakingView = (TextView) contentView.findViewById(R.id.breaking);

        //set description view
        textView = (WebView) contentView.findViewById(descriptionView);
        textView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            }
        });
        //enable javascript
        textView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        textView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                if (url != null && url.startsWith("http")) {
                    view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

        });

        //get item
        ItemId = getArguments().getInt(SingleNewsArticleActivity.ITEM_KEY);

        //comment button
        final Button commentsBtn = (Button) contentView.findViewById(R.id.commentsBtn);
        commentsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // launching Facebook comments activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), CommentsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("url", Configurations.SERVER_URL + ItemId);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        //load article
        NewsArticle.loadSingle(getActivity(), ItemId, new NewsArticle.onDownloadedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloaded(NewsArticle newsArticleLocal) {
                if (getActivity() != null) {
                    newsArticleLocal.viewed(getContext());
                    newsArticle = newsArticleLocal;

                    //set title and text
                    titleView.setText(newsArticle.name);
                    textView.loadData(Functions.HTMLTemplate(newsArticle.text), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");

                    //author
                    String author = "";
                    if (Preference.getCached(getContext(), "showauthorname").equals("1")) {
                        if (newsArticle.authorName.length() > 0)
                            author = " - " + newsArticle.authorName;
                    }

                    //date
                    String DateToStr = PrettyTime.getTimeAgo(newsArticle.submission_date, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", getActivity());
                    dateView.setText(DateToStr + author);

                    if (newsArticle.allowComments == 1)
                        commentsBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    else
                        commentsBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    //breaking
                    if (newsArticle.is_breaking == 1) {
                        breakingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        breakingView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    //set image if in feature mode
                    if (isFeatureImage) {
                        //set image
                        if (newsArticle.imageUrl != null) {
                            Picasso.with(getContext())
                                    .load(newsArticle.imageUrl[0])
                                    .fit()
                                    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                                    .into(propertyImage);
                        }

                    }
                    logDeepLinkAction(newsArticle.name,Configurations.SERVER_URL + newsArticle.id);
                    indexNewsContent(newsArticle.name,newsArticle.text,Configurations.SERVER_URL + newsArticle.id);
                }
            }
        });
        return fragmentContentView;
    }


    /**
     * Open images in full screen mode
     */
    public void openFullScreenImage() {
        if(newsArticle==null)
            return;
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putStringArray("imageUrl", newsArticle.imageUrl);
        b.putInt("slideshow_seconds", Configurations.SLIDESHOW_TIME_SECONDS);
        Intent i = new Intent(getContext(), FullScreenImage.class);
        i.putExtras(b);
        startActivity(i);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.single_news_menu, menu);

        //set share icon from FontAwsome
        menu.findItem(R.id.share).setIcon(
                new IconicsDrawable(getContext())
                        .icon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_share_alt)
                        .color(ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.md_white_1000))
                        .sizeDp(18));

        //set bookmark icon from FontAwesome
        boolean isFavorite = (NewsArticle.isFavoriteById(getActivity(), ItemId));
        if (isFavorite) {
            menu.findItem(R.id.bookmark).setIcon(new IconicsDrawable(getActivity())
                    .icon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_bookmark)
                    .color(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.md_white_1000))
                    .sizeDp(18));
        } else {
            menu.findItem(R.id.bookmark).setIcon(new IconicsDrawable(getActivity())
                    .icon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_bookmark_o)
                    .color(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.md_white_1000))
                    .sizeDp(18));

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle share
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.share:
                NewsArticle.shareById(getActivity(), ItemId);
                return true;

            case R.id.bookmark:
                boolean isFavorite = (NewsArticle.isFavoriteById(getActivity(), ItemId));
                NewsArticle.setFavoriteById(getActivity(), !isFavorite, ItemId);
                if (isFavorite) {
                    item.setIcon(new IconicsDrawable(getActivity())
                            .icon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_bookmark_o)
                            .color(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.md_white_1000))
                            .sizeDp(18));
                } else {
                    item.setIcon(new IconicsDrawable(getActivity())
                            .icon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_bookmark)
                            .color(ContextCompat.getColor(getActivity(), R.color.md_white_1000))
                            .sizeDp(18));
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        textView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        textView.onResume();
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        textView.destroy();

    }

    private void indexNewsContent(final String name,String desc, String url) {

        Indexable contentIndex = new Indexable.Builder()
                .setName(name)
                .setUrl(url)
                .setDescription(desc)
                .build();

        Task<Void> task =
                FirebaseAppIndex.getInstance().update(contentIndex);

        task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                Log.d("Content Indexing", "App Indexing added "
                        + name + " to " +
                        "index");
            }
        });

        task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                Log.e("Content Indexing", "App Indexing failed to add " +
                        name + " to index. " +
                        "" + exception.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private void logDeepLinkAction(final String title, final String url) {
        Action action = Actions.newView(title, url);
        FirebaseUserActions.getInstance().end(action);
    }

}
```

My **layout** is :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhiteBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/breaking"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:background="@color/color_breaking_news"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:text="@string/breaking"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textDirection="locale"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textSize="24sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

        <Button
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:background="@color/accent"
            android:id="@+id/commentsBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/comments" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: That is weird. Usually this error occurs when you have padding in your parent layout. But in your case you don't have any. Can you change the width of the AdView to `match_parent` instead of `wrap_content`.

Comment: Thanks, @nupadhyaya I tried it but doesn't solve my problem. :(

Comment: Try changing your layout to the one i pasted in my answer below. I think the scroll view is messing the adView

Comment: @nupadhyaya i tried it and nothing happened. I just update the SingleNewsArticleFragment file can you check it, please ?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhiteBackground"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/breaking"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:background="@color/color_breaking_news"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:paddingBottom="3dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:text="@string/breaking"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textDirection="locale"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:visibility="gone" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textSize="24sp" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dateView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorSecondaryText"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/descriptionView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textSize="14sp" />


        <Button
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_margin="30dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@color/md_white_1000"
            android:background="@color/accent"
            android:id="@+id/commentsBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/comments" />


    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: W/Ads: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 0x686 dp.



W/Ads: Not enough space to show ad. Needs 320x50 dp, but only has 0x630 dp.

Answer (score 0):

your admob tag should be like this in your xml file :

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

and it should be below your scroll view tag.

Comment: Thanks, @unzila I tried it and nothing happened. I just update the SingleNewsArticleFragment file can you check it, please?

Comment: @SultanAlmalki  in your fragment add these lines so your ad will be working fine. Add this in onpause and onresume of fragment
 if (adView != null) adView.pause(); if (adView!= null) adView.resume();

Comment: and is a good practice to add admob inside of activity instead of fragment. because fragments are portion of activity so your admob functionality should be inside of activity.